# Solve quadratic related problem without brute force/trial and error or quadratic formula.

Tags: geometry, quadratics, area, completing-the-square

At least I need to explain to an 11 year old

> One square is cut out of another. Side lengths of each square are whole numbers less than 25. Remaining area of larger is 57. What is perimeter of smaller square?

Obviously we can use excel to find B (bigger), L (littler, if that's even a word) s.t
$B^2 - L^2 = 57$ namely B=11,L=8 but I think there is some simple trick to this that I'm overlooking like we would be able to compute 4L without directly computing B or L. Completing the square?

Like

$B^2 - 57 - 4L + 4 = L^2 - 4L + 4$

Side question: is quadratic formula even helpful here? I think we are still going to do trial and error

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Use $$B^2-L^2=(B-L)(B+L)=57$$ For every pair $(u,v)$ with $uv=57$, solve the linear equation system $$B-L=u$$ $$B+L=v$$ This should be faster than trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, we have:

$B^{2} -L^{2} = 57 \Rightarrow (B+L)(B-L) = 57$

Factorising $57$: $57 = 19 \cdot 3$

Since $B,L \in \mathbb{N}$, and $B>L$, we get $B+L = 19, B-L = 3$

This gives us $B = 11$ and $L = 8$. So the perimeter of the smaller square is $32$

Edit: note we also get the solution $B = 29, L = 28$, but we reject these using the initial condition $B,L < 25$

Comment: You are missing the solution $B=29,L=28\,$ which works as well, but is excluded by the "*less than 25*" condition.

Comment: The question gives the condition that $B,L <25$

Comment: Right, but you can only check that condition *after* you found all solutions, so that's worth pointing out in the answer.

Comment: Fair point, I included those extra solutions (although you could also make an argument then to include the negative solutions as well)

Comment: Side lengths are always assumed to be positive, but must be $\lt 25$ in this problem, only. So you can safely ignore factorizations like $(-19)\cdot(-3)\,$ but you can only reject $57 \cdot 1$ after determining that the solution violates the additional constraint.